# Почему нельзя записывать в переменные значение стилей

Tags: javascript

Почему нельзя записывать в переменные значение стилей?

```
var display = login.style.display
//display == пусто
```

Comment: alert(login.style.display);
Выводит что?

Comment: пусто(((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значит сама "login.style.display" пуста, раз ты алертом её вывести не можешь.

Comment: почему она пуста я же в сss прописал display: none;?

Comment: хм...а если стиль прописать не через CSS, а через тот же ява?

Comment: CSS стиль и стиль элемента 2 АБСОЛЮТНО разные вещи.

Грубо - способом `el.style.someSteleProp` вы можете прочитать только те стили которые так или иначе (то-ли сразу в html, то-ли динамические т.е. инициализированные с помощью JS )